# Freeze background activity when Progress Bar is running

Tags: android

I am a facing a problem in my app.Actually,there is an activity in which i send an image to server.In xml layout file i use a progress bar view.The progress bar start loading when image is loading to server and dismiss when the work done.Everything working fine.The problem is that when progress bar is in running state the background activity is still active.I want to freeze the background activity while progress bar is in runnung state.The code is as follows.

```
postPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v){


        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run() {


                //here the code to post image to server 

                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


                }


            }.start();
            }

        }

        private  Handler handler = new Handler() {
             @Override
             public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                 try {


                     mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                        }

                      else  if(messagePostingItems.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){

                        startActivity(new Intent(PostPhoto.this,PostPicDialog.class));

                     }
            };
    });
```

Please help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate pattern if you want to 'freeze' the activity whilst doing something else is to use an AlertDialog. Put the progress bar on the dialog, and whenever the action is done, dismiss the dialog.

But remember that the use can click the Home button anytime he/she wants, that will give you some extra headache.

Answer (score 0):

finally i have done that.Those who are facing the same problem,my solution will definitely help them out.
Just make the object of Dialog class in your activity class.

```
Dialog mdialog=new Dialog(this);

    mdialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mdialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog);
    mdialog.getWindow ().setBackgroundDrawableResource (android.R.color.transparent);


    mdialog.show();
```

The custom_progress_dialog is as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbCustomDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't.

'freezing the background activity' is the UI thread, if you attempt to stop the UI thread, you will cause an ANR (Activity Not Responding) and the user will have the option to force close your app.

If however you want to stop whatever it is that your saying is 'still moving' then you should do this in your onClick method alongside showing the dialog and dismissing it. One easy solution is to start a new Activity that houses your progress dialog and a white background. Then the activity lifecycle does most the work for you.

Or put your ProgressBar in a Dialog i.e. [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) and show this to the user. This is called a modal dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Use AsyncTask.....
for eg..

```
private class abc extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
                    //start the progress dialog
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //dismiss the dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //send image to server code
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then in your onCreate() method call

```
new abc().execute();
```